# How to input multiple rows into django database with one submission in django

Tags: python, django, forms, input

I have a for loop with hidden input in each. I try to input it into a transaction database with:

```
Models.py
class TransDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    sumprice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)
    no_note = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    no_nota = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_nota = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)
    tanggal = models.CharField(max_length=200)


HTML Template
              <table>
                 <tbody>
                    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'transactionadd' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for name,amount,price,sumprice in x %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{name}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{name}}">
                        </td>
                        <td>{{amount}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value={{amount}}>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{price}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="price" value={{price}}>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{sumprice}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="sumprice" value={{sumprice}}>
                            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value={{no_nota}}>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="no_nota" value={{no_nota}}>
                <input type="hidden" name="total_nota" value={{sumcart}}>
                <input type="hidden" name="tanggal" value={{now}}>
                <h3> Your cart total is {{sumcart}}</h3>
                <hr/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-success">Confirm</button>
            </form>

Views.py
def transactionadd(request):
    form1 = TransForm(request.POST or None)
    form2 = TransDetailForm(request.POST or None)
    if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        form1.save()
        form2.save()
        messages.success(request,"Transaction recorded")
        Cart.objects.all().delete()
        return redirect('index')

    context={
        'form1':form1,
        'form2':form2
    }

    return render(request, 'cart.html', context)
```

The problem is everytime I confirm the transaction, only one entry line (the latest object) is being inputed into the database. Let say I put a hamburger and a hot dog into the cart and create a transaction. In the transaction detail database I will only get the hot dog but not the hamburger. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forms are not prefixed that's why just the last one is used.

If you want to add multiple objects of the same type with a form your should use a formset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Here is explained how you can easily add new entries with javascript: https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/dynamic-add-form-with-add-button-in-django-modelformset-template/